# Network Marketing Binary tree

Tags: php, oop, tree, binary-tree

I'm creating some network marketing code and I'm thinking of using PHP object oriented proramming. I was wondering how I could proceed with the code.

It's a Binary Tree of objects. Thus having only left and right children. Is their any source code I could study for this?

I have created one already but is in C#, and I'm not too familiar with PHP OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need some code like this? If you already had a C# version, I think it is easy to change to PHP with this sample.

```
class Node
{
    private $left;
    private $right;
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function search($key)
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}

class BinaryTree
{
    private $root;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->root = new Node();
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```